# Hosting a Mongo DB with a scheduled Python Script

Tags: python, mongodb, hosting, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for a hosting service to run my python scripts. My python scripts take info from various API's and put them into a Mongo database. I'd like to schedule them so that they run once an hour. Right now I'm running python 2.6 and using a couple of extra packages like facebook sdk and python twitter tools. I've been looking into heroku, but I'm new to the service and I'm having trouble finding documentation on heroku and python. The other service that I came across is MongoHQ, but I'm unsure as to how that works with Python. Do you know of a hosting service that would be compatible with all of these things?

**EDIT**

I took the advice below and explored DotCloud a bit. For anybody who's a newb like I am, I wrote a post on it on my blog ([swootsblog.cloudfoundry.com](http://swootsblog.cloudfoundry.com)) which I hope is pretty easy to follow along with. It's a continuously running python script writing to a MongoDB all set up on DotCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't run Python, they only run Ruby, Node.js, Clojure and Java.

There might be other services, but I've played around with [DotCloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/) which has a [python worker](http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/python-worker/) type for exactly this sort of work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'm looking at Dotcloud now and seeing if it would be good for my project. The other host that I investigated was webfaction, which looked appealing because of its good customer service.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Does runs python scripts, I have previously done this with python to postgres database,

**Pre-req**

```
pythonscripts.py
procfile
requirements.txt
```

and After add, commit and push the scripts to heroku app. Just run the following command on terminal to run the scripts.

```
heroku run python your_scripts.py
```

More if you want to run this scripts on a schedule timing. then heroku provides lots of adds-on. just search it on heroku

If you need more help, make a chat with me.